# How to remove single object from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object, slice

i am trying to remove one single object from a nested array.My case is Array have identical objects in it multiple times and i should be like that. so how can i remove one single object from array , even they are identical objects in it.
my past attempts are `filter` and `slice` methods.But they are actually removing all identical objects at one time.

```
const data = {
    { id:1, name:'test'},
    { id:1, name:'test'},
    { id:1, name:'test'},
    { id:2, name:'test2'},
    { id:2, name:'test2'},
}
```

expected result after one execution :

```
    { id:1, name:'test'},
    { id:1, name:'test'},
    { id:2, name:'test2'},
    { id:2, name:'test2'},
```

Comment: what are your conditions? need to keep 2 entries of duplicate objects?

Comment: do you know the array position of the object?

Comment: remove which one of the duplicates? first, last, second ? we need a condition

Comment: @MihaiT pretty sure if they are duplicates it doesn't matter 'which' we remove, only that the correct number remains when we are done

Comment: it's a collection ? in case it should be inside squared brackets [] and you should use `Array.prototype.splice.call(data, indexToRemove, 1);` or if it's an object you should use `delete data[keyToRemove];`

Comment: The correct way to remove an element from an array is with `Array.splice` (note: splice is not slice). So to remove the 5th element (element 4) from an array called data, it'd be `data.splice(4, 1)`. That won't remove anything other than element 4. But the code you provided has improper syntax (arrays are indicated by [], not {}; objects which use {} need a key for each property, which yours doesn't). So I don't know if perhaps your array is improperly created in the first place?

Comment: these are actually part of my redux store , where i need to take same item multiple times into cart and then checkout . so i want to keep duplicate objects and to remove only one when clicked so

Comment: @vamshikrishna The code above is not a valid JS structure...and its definetally not an **array**. I would suggest first get to know the array astructure and atleast how to type one and then try to implement what you wanted in a first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> these are actually part of my redux store , where i need to take same item multiple times into cart and then checkout . so i want to keep duplicate objects and to remove only one when clicked so

taking from this response I'm going to guess that you need to store the index of the object when displaying it in (React? whatever framework) then when you dispatch an action to remove_item pass the index as the payload. Hard to say for sure without a minimal complete example, but with those givens you would need to:

```js
const data = {
  items: [
    { id:1, name:'test'},
    { id:1, name:'test'},
    { id:1, name:'test'},
    { id:2, name:'test2'},
    { id:2, name:'test2'},
  ],
};

const removeItem = (items, index) => ([ ...items.slice(0, index), ...items.slice(index + 1)]);

console.log(data);
data.items = [ ...removeItem(data.items, 2) ] ;
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Why are you reproducing `Array.splice` by combining two calls to `Array.slice` and a spread operator? Seems like you're overcomplicating things.

Comment: @IceMetalPunk, solid question. array splice is a mutator function that returns the deleted elements not the remaining elements. In the case of Redux you always favor returning a new object (immutablilty). So yes slightly more complex, but neither overly so or without purpose.

Comment: @D Lowther If you're overwriting the original array with a new one, it will be garbage collected anyway. But if you really want to return a new array, it's still better to just copy the array and splice that one instead of slicing it twice and spreading it thrice :)